# Doubt in the Proof on Dehn-Nielsen-Baer theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, mapping-class-group

I'm reading the proof of Dehn-Nielsen-Baer theorem given in the book 'A primer on mapping class groups' by Margalit and Farb. I'm having trouble understanding the following line from the proof of lemma 8.5.
"Assume for the purposes of contradiction that  $\Phi(\gamma)$ and
$\Phi(\delta)$ are linked at infinity. It follows that the polygonal paths $\{\Phi(\alpha_i)\}$ and $\{\Phi(\beta_i)\}$ have to cross."
Since $\Phi(\gamma)$ and
$\Phi(\delta)$ are linked at infinity thier axes intersect. But what is the exact relation between the axes of $\Phi(\gamma)$ and
$\Phi(\delta)$ and the polygonal paths that forces them to intersect?

Answer (score 1):

To review the setting in more detail, we have two embeddings of $[0,1]$ in the closed disc $D^2$ with images $A$ and $B$:

- $A$ is the closure of $\Phi(\gamma) = \text{interior}(A) = A \cap \text{interior}(D^2)$ with endpoints $\partial A = \{a_0,a_1\} = A \cap S^1$;
- $B$ is the closure of $\Phi(\delta) = \text{interior}(B) = B \cap \text{interior}(D^2)$ with endpoints $\partial B = \{b_0,b_1\} = B \cap S^1$.

To say that "$\Phi(\gamma)$ and $\Phi(\delta)$ are linked at infinity" means that the two sets $\partial A,\partial B \subset S^1$ are linked in $S^1$, which in turn means that there exists a parameterization $[0,2\pi] \mapsto S^1$ in the usual fashion (continuous, surjective, and injective except that $0,2\pi$ are mapped to the same point of $S^1$), and there exist parameters $0 < s_0 < t_0 < s_1 < t_1 < 2\pi$, such that
$$s_0 \mapsto a_0, \quad t_0 \mapsto b_0, \quad s_1 \mapsto a_1, \quad t_1 \mapsto b_1
$$
Another way to say this without parameterizations is that each of the two components of the set $S^1 - \{a_1,a_2\}$ contains a point of $\{b_1,b_2\}$.

That answers your question about what the exact relation is.

The way that you then get the desired conclusion is by applying a theorem of topology:

> For any two embeddings of $[0,1]$ in $D^2$ denoted $A,B \subset D^2$, if $A \cap S^1 = \partial A$ and $B \cap S^1 = \partial B$, and if $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ are linked in $S^1$ (as defined above), then $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$.

This can be proved by doubling $D^2$ along $S^1$ to obtain a 2-sphere, in which there is an embedded circle obtained by doubling $A$ along $\partial A$, and then applying the Jordan Curve Theorem.

Comment: It seems you have misunderstood the question. I wanted to know the exact relation between the "polygonal paths" and the axes of  $\Phi(\gamma)$  and $\Phi(\delta)$. It is intuitively clear that the polygonal paths must run parallel to the axes of $\Phi(\gamma)$  and $\Phi(\delta)$ and hence they should intersect. But I am unable to make this precise.

Comment: I think I have a solution. Since $\Phi(\gamma)$ and $\Phi(\delta)$ can be extended to continuous functions on $D^2$. The two endpoints of their axes are the fixed points of $\Phi(\gamma)$ and $\Phi(\delta)$. Taking limits $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Phi(\gamma^{n}(x_0))$ and $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Phi(\gamma^{-n}(x_0))$ we get two endpoints. Using this we can conclude that the polygonal paths $\{ \Phi(\alpha_i))\}$ and $\{ \Phi(\beta_i))\}$ lie in neighborhoods of the axes of $\Phi(\gamma)$ and $\Phi(\delta)$ and thus they must intersect. Please check this once.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get as much control over these polygonal paths as to say that they "lie in neighborhoods" of the axes, except insofar as the entire open disc is a neighborhood. You can feel free to try to find a low level proof that these paths intersect. But if you want to get a short proof which uses standard topological tools, I doubt you'll find one shorter than this application of the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: Anyway, to repeat in different words, the exact relation between the axes and the paths which forces the paths to intersect is that each path has the same endpoints (on $S^1$) as the axis to which it corresponds.